# Main menu alias links

Tags: theming

my current menu links are generated but those are not the alias urls as follows:

```
theme('links__system_main_menu', array('links' => $main_menu, 'attributes' => array('class' => array('nav nav-pills'))));
```

I would like that the menu generated is with alias urls instead the 'content/name-of-node'. How do you generated menu with alias path links? Is there function i can get only array of links for the main manu, so i can parse out the html myself? Thank You for help

p.s. This is Drupal 7.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question, but have you looked at `menu_build_tree()` and `menu_load_links()`? The menu API is https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21menu.inc/7

Answer (score 0):

Thank You Chris...the menu_load_links() was exactly what i was looking for. Here is my custom main menu array that i later parse in html teplates as needed:

```
$mainMenuArray = menu_load_links('main-menu');
$finalMainMenu = array();
foreach($mainMenuArray as $key=>$menuItem){
    $finalMainMenu[$key]['active'] = false;
    $linkPath = $menuItem['link_path'];
    $linkPathAlias = drupal_get_path_alias($linkPath);
    $currentId = $vars['node']->nid;
    if(drupal_get_path_alias("node/$currentId") == $linkPathAlias)$finalMainMenu[$key]['active'] = true;
    $finalMainMenu[$key]['url'] = $linkPathAlias;
    $finalMainMenu[$key]['title'] = $menuItem['link_title'];
}
$vars['mainMenu'] = $finalMainMenu;
```

I have this in template.php hook 'theme_preprocess_page' where the $vars['node'] is used to determine what is the current node loaded. I hope it useful for someone. Thank you Chris for answering my question.